# Can iOS delete folders from command line?

Tags: ios, terminal, jailbreak

I have a button in my Preference Bundle for my iOS tweak and I'm trying to have it delete a cache file so that the tweak will work properly.

The function for the button is here

```
- (void)respring {
        system("cd /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards");
        system("rm -R images");
        system("rm version");
}
```

When I go into iFile afterwords the file is still there and hasn't deleted.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Do you plan on writing a bash script? Otherwise I don't see the point of using command line tools instead of iOS APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but my guess is that you are running **three** separate commands, with `system()`.

So, you run one command to change directory, and then nothing else.

The second command to `rm -R images` is then run by itself, and not performed with `/var/mobile/Library/Caches` as the current directory.

You might try simply combining all three commands into one:

```
system("cd /var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.keyboards; rm -R images; rm version");
```

If that doesn't work, report back and maybe there's another problem.